# Dynamic insert?

Tags: apex, dynamic-apex

I wonder if it is possible to create a dynamic insert where I can pass which fields I want to insert.
This need arose because every time I need to enter information into an object in different record types, I have to create different methods as the fields change.

So I wanted something like this:

```
Indicador_Clinico__c indic = new Indicador_Clinico__c();

        indic.diseaseActivityIndex__c = 'example';
        indic.Score__c                = 'example';
        indic.RecordTypeId            = 'example';
        indic.COD_CONSULTA__c         = 'example';
        insert indic;
```

If it became dynamic like this:

```
Indicador_Clinico__c indic = new Indicador_Clinico__c();

        indic.field1 = 'example';
        indic.field2 = 'example';
        indic.field3 = 'example';
        indic.field4 = 'example';
        insert indic;
```

One last thing is that the idea is that the number of fields also changes. I kept the same amount above just as an example.

So the first insert I put here could turn into this:

```
Indicador_Clinico__c indic = new Indicador_Clinico__c();

        indic.field1 = 'test';
        indic.field2 = 'test';
        insert indic;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Sobject's put](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_put_2) method to dynamically provide field names and values

```
Indicador_Clinico__c indic = new Indicador_Clinico__c();
indic.put('MyField__c','JAR');
```

Comment: Thanks @Pranay Jaiswal! Another thing: can "My_field" in your example be a variable?
Example: indic.put(varField,'JAR');

Comment: @DiegoEdargoPessoa sure, it can be a variable :)

Comment: One last thing @Pranay, the value in field can be a variable too? Like: indic.put(varfield, varvalue);

Comment: I can't see why not